# JavaScript implementation doesnt work (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I am using JSF to write a web application. I found a nice line graph on codepen that I would like to implement on my page. [Here](http://codepen.io/codeschubser/pen/PwajYp) is said graph. Because I know absolutely nothing about JavaScript I am having some trouble implementing it in my page. Could someone help me to implement this?

I tried to copy paste his code into my page but this obviously did not work.

What my page currently looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
    <ui:include src="head.xhtml" />
    <script src="js/chart.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css"rel="stylesheet"href="webjars/bootswatchyeti/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"  />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css"  />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<h:body>
...
```

Comment: Can you try like this way? http://jsfiddle.net/ucbkosut/

Comment: @guvenckardas This solved it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget 'mark as an answer' and vote up:) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is demo for you:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ucbkosut)

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chart in Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<script>

    window.onload= function(){
        $('#modChart').on('shown.bs.modal',function(event){
            var link = $(event.relatedTarget);
            // get data source
            var source = link.attr('data-source').split(',');
            // get title
            var title = link.html();
            // get labels
            var table = link.parents('table');
            var labels = [];
            $('#'+table.attr('id')+'>thead>tr>th').each(function(index,value){
                // without first column
                if(index>0){labels.push($(value).html());}
            });
            // get target source
            var target = [];
            $.each(labels, function(index,value){
                target.push(link.attr('data-target-source'));
            });
            // Chart initialisieren
            var modal = $(this);
            var canvas = modal.find('.modal-body canvas');
            modal.find('.modal-title').html(title);
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line({
                responsive: true,
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: source
                },{
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "#F7464A",
                    pointColor: "#FF5A5E",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#FF5A5E",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "red",
                    data: target
                }]
            },{});
        }).on('hidden.bs.modal',function(event){
            // reset canvas size
            var modal = $(this);
            var canvas = modal.find('.modal-body canvas');
            canvas.attr('width','568px').attr('height','300px');
            // destroy modal
            $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        });
    }


</script>

<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="business_ratio" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-charts">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Business ratio</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Jan.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Feb.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Mar.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Apr.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">May</th>
                        <th class="text-center">June</th>
                        <th class="text-center">July</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Aug.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Sept.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Oct.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Nov.</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Dec.</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modChart" data-source="65.1,59.47,80.00,81.11,56.67,55.45,40.88,20.45,40.98,80.66,88.34,61.01" data-target-source="50">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> Example
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">65.10</td>
                        <td class="text-right">59.47</td>
                        <td class="text-right">80.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">81.11</td>
                        <td class="text-right">56.67</td>
                        <td class="text-right">55.45</td>
                        <td class="text-right">40.88</td>
                        <td class="text-right">20.45</td>
                        <td class="text-right">40.98</td>
                        <td class="text-right">80.66</td>
                        <td class="text-right">88.34</td>
                        <td class="text-right">61.01</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modChart" data-source="70,13,20,90,44,12,30,30,30,10,5,0" data-target-source="34">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> Foobar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">70</td>
                        <td class="text-right">13</td>
                        <td class="text-right">20</td>
                        <td class="text-right">90</td>
                        <td class="text-right">44</td>
                        <td class="text-right">12</td>
                        <td class="text-right">30</td>
                        <td class="text-right">30</td>
                        <td class="text-right">30</td>
                        <td class="text-right">10</td>
                        <td class="text-right">5</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modChart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Linechart</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <canvas id="canvas" width="568" height="300"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```